# Conditional statement limiting the number of displayed elements

Tags: javascript, html, json, if-statement, fetch

I'm having trouble implementing the logic that will limit me from adding the same items to my shopping list. When the item is the same, I just want to display the quantity with the existing item.

```
    <div class="pizzas">
    </div>
    <div class="shoppingCart">
        <p class="totalPrice">Hungry? order our pizzas</p>
    </div>

// js

fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexsimkovich/patronage/main/api/data.json")
.then(data => data.json())
.then(data => {
let valueCurrency = 0;
data.forEach(element => {
    const shoppingCart = document.querySelector(".shoppingCart");
    const pizzas = document.querySelector(".pizzas");
    const box = document.createElement("div");
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    const title = document.createElement("h3");
    const ingredients = document.createElement("p");
    const price = document.createElement("h4");
    const btn = document.createElement("button");
    const totalPrice = document.querySelector(".totalPrice");
     
    box.className = "box";
    ingredients.className = "ingredients"
    btn.className = "btn";
    img.src = element.image;
    img.className = "img";
     
    title.innerHTML = element.title;
    ingredients.innerHTML = element.ingredients;
    price.innerHTML = element.price.toFixed(2) + " zł";
    btn.innerHTML = "Dodaj do koszyka";
     
    box.appendChild(img);
    box.appendChild(title);
    box.appendChild(ingredients);
    box.appendChild(price);
    box.appendChild(btn);
    pizzas.appendChild(box);


    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        valueCurrency = valueCurrency + element.price;

        const pizza = document.createElement("div");
        pizza.className = "pizzaList";
        const pizzasList = document.createElement("li");
        const pizzaPrice = document.createElement("p");
        const btnRemove = document.createElement("button");
        btnRemove.innerText = "X";
         
        pizzasList.innerText = title.textContent;
        pizzaPrice.innerText = price.textContent;

        pizza.appendChild(pizzasList);
        pizza.appendChild(pizzaPrice);
        pizza.appendChild(btnRemove);

        totalPrice.innerText = "Całkowita cena: " + valueCurrency.toFixed(2);

        if(pizzasList.innerText === pizzasList.innerText)
        {
            // don't add another item to the list
            // just add +1 to existing element
        }
        else
        {
            // add an item to the list
            shoppingCart.prepend(pizza);

        }

        btnRemove.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            pizza.remove();
            valueCurrency = valueCurrency - element.price;
            totalPrice.innerText = "Całkowita cena: " + valueCurrency.toFixed(2);
        })
    })

});
 
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

My problem is exactly in the conditional statement, I don't know exactly how to implement the counting of the same pizzas option.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using html elements for this, what you can do is to use a data-attribute in your pizza element and increment it each time you need.

Something like:

```
if(pizzasList === pizzasList)
{
  pizza.dataset.total = Number(pizza.dataset.total) + 1;
}
else
{
  pizza.dataset.total = 1;
  shoppingCart.prepend(pizza);
}
```

Then just use `pizza.dataset.total` to retieve the total number of repetitions.

Comment: unfortunately the condition is spelled wrong and doesn't work well

Comment: you want to know what to write on the condition or inside it? Anyway i think your approach is not the best, why you use html elements to save data? Why not use just simple data-structures like objects or arrays?

Comment: I tried adding individual pizzas to the board, but had some implementation problems and let it go. I thought that I could do it somehow in the condition where when the same pizza appears, it will only be added to the existing item, not added to the list again. I want to know what to write on the condition.

Comment: I think you need to add some identifier to your pizzas, like an ID, so you can compare them and see if they were already ordered or not

Comment: I have no ideas anymore, I only have this one thing to implement and it gives up a bit

Comment: You must re-do your code, that does no make any sense